# Change from italics to normal text

Tags: fonts, sectioning

In a new section instead of normal text i have italics, how to change it to normal text? I know that `\normaltext` works, but i want to change in the whole article.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{polski} 
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[polish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{bbm} 
\begin{document} 
\newtheorem{tw}{Twierdzenie}[section] 
\newtheorem{df}{Definicja}[section] 
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemat}[section] 
\section{Wstęp} 
\tw{Jakies twierdzenie} 
bala 
\section{Inna} 
Balala 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be italic by default. Show us an example.

Comment: As @AhaanRungta suggests, please post a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your problem. Otherwise we really can't be helpful.

Comment: I've copied your MWE from the comment into the main body of your posting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage of defined theorems is `\begin{tw} Theorem text \end{tw}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bbm}

\newtheorem{tw}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\newtheorem{df}{Definicja}[section]
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemat}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Wstęp}

\begin{tw}
Jakies twierdzenie
\end{tw}

bala

\section{Inna}

Balala

\end{document}
```

Please, put `\newtheorem` in the preamble, to keep the declarations seperate from the article contents. As well, I believe that `\usepackage{polski}` is deprecated (`babel` should be enough).

Comment: Since it seems that this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This way it is clear as well to others that the question is solved. Thanks!